# Defer Eclipse Treeviewer loading by DeferredTreeContentManager

Tags: eclipse, jface, treeviewer, deferred-loading

I understand there is an approach to defer `TreeViewer` loading by using `DeferredTreeContentManager`, learnt from this useful [tutorial](http://www.eclipseworld.org/bbs/simple/?t1915.html).

However, this mechanism requires the model to implement `IDeferredWorkbenchAdapter` interface, which introduces problem to my legacy immutable model classes. Is it possible to use `DeferredTreeContentManager` without having model implementing `IDeferredWorkbenchAdapter` interface?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that I can use AdapterFactory to covert the model to IDeferredWorkbenchAdapter. Problem solved!